# Fetching JSON in Perl

Tags: json, perl, http, get, mojolicious

I've been working building an emulator in Perl and one of the issues I'm facing is parsing JSON files located in the computer. When I try fetching them from my server, they work fine...

```
    method getContent(\@arrURLS) {
    my %arrInfo;
    my $resUserAgent = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    foreach my $strURL (@arrURLS) {
        $resUserAgent->get($strURL => sub {
            my($resUserAgent, $tx) = @_;
            if ($tx->success) {
                my $strName = basename($strURL, '.json');
                my $arrData = $tx->res->body;
                $arrInfo{$strName} = $arrData;
            }
            Mojo::IOLoop->stop;
        });
        Mojo::IOLoop->start;
    }
    return \%arrInfo;
}
```

Let's assume `@arrURLS` is:

```
my @arrURLS = ("file:///C:/Users/Test/Desktop/JSONS/first.json", "file:///C:/Users/Test/Desktop/JSONS/second.json");
```

The above url's are the one's that aren't working, however if I change that to:

```
my @arrURLS = ("http://127.0.0.1/test/json/first.json", "http://127.0.0.1/test/json/second.json");
```

it works.

Also I would like to use something better than `Mojo::UserAgent` because it seems a bit slow, when I was using `Coro` with `LWP::Simple` it was much faster but unfortunately `Coro` is broken in Perl 5.22...

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.martin-evans.me.uk/node/169 regarding the speed.

Comment: `Mojo::UserAgent` objects support *only* the `http` scheme. You would be better off using `LWP::UserAgent` instead, which transparently supports `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `file`, `mailto` and others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User Agents are mainly for downloading files through http. They are usually not expected to handle filesystem URIs. You need to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [read the file](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) yourself, or use a module like [File::Slurp](http://p3rl.org/File::Slurp) that does it for you.

It could look something like this.

```
use File::Slurp 'read_file';

method getContent(\@arrURLS) {
    my %arrInfo;
    my $resUserAgent = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    foreach my $strURL (@arrURLS) {
        if (substr($strURL, 0, 4) eq 'file') {
            $arrInfo{basename($strURL, '.json')} = read_file($strURL);
        } else {
            $resUserAgent->get($strURL => sub {
                my($resUserAgent, $tx) = @_;
                if ($tx->success) {
                    my $strName = basename($strURL, '.json');
                    my $arrData = $tx->res->body;
                    $arrInfo{$strName} = $arrData;
                }
                Mojo::IOLoop->stop;
            });
            Mojo::IOLoop->start;
        }
    }
    return \%arrInfo;
}
```

Comment: Note that File::Slurp has severe problems https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83126

Answer (score 2):

Myself using [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) for all such tasks. From the doc:

> WWW::Mechanize is a proper subclass of LWP::UserAgent and you can also
>   use any of LWP::UserAgent's methods.

what means you can feed it with `file://` type URLs too.

For example, the following one-liner dumps your `passwd` file.

```
perl -MWWW::Mechanize -E 'say WWW::Mechanize->new->get("file://etc/passwd")->content'
```

or an example without any error handling...

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('file://some/path');
say $mech->content;
```

Anyway, probably is better to use for local files some `file-based` utility, myself using for all file-things the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module, which has (not limited only) an method for file slurping, such:

```
use Path::Tiny;
my $content = path('/some/path')->slurp;
```

or just plain perl:

```
open my $fh, '<', '/some/file' or die "...";
my $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;
```

Comment: I like the Path::Tiny approach and have never used it. But I would not recommend using Mechanize for a simple downloading task in production, unless you want to click a bunch of stuff before downloading.

Comment: I prefer Web::Scraper, but I use Mechanize very heavily in the Test:: flavour.

Comment: @jm666: *"On the other side, you need learn one thing for most of your needs"* Yes, but the downside is that you *have* only learned one thing. It is useful to understand *LWP* because it will do far more than the naive `WWW::Mechanize` interface implies, and [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) is very useful for a different set of problems. If you always throw a nuke at either a planet or a soldier then you aren't using your armoury well

Answer (score 1):

It's important always to say what additional modules you're using. I think your code uses [`Method::Signatures`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Method::Signatures), and I've tested the code below only to check that it compiles with that module in place

*Mojolicious* is an excellent tool for its purpose, but it is focused on HTTP URLs. [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) is much more general-purpose, and the [documentation for `LWP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) says this

> Provides an object oriented model of HTTP-style communication. Within this framework we currently support access to http, https, gopher, ftp, news, file, and mailto resources

Your method becomes something like this. It's untested

```
method get_content(\@urls) {

    my %info;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
 
    for my $url (@urls) {

        my $res = $ua->get($url);
        die $res->status_line unless $res->is_success;

        my $name     = basename($url) . '.json';
        my $data     = $res->decoded_content;
        $info{$name} = $data;
    }

    \%info;
}
```

---

I would also encourage you to drop Hungarian notation in the context of Perl code, as the language already has its sigils that denote the data type

`@arrURLS` duplicates the information that this `arrURLS` is an array, while `%arrInfo` is just wrong as this `arrInfo` is a *hash*. `$arrData` is actually a *scalar*, although perhaps some indicator that it is also a *reference* may help, and `$arrURLS[0]` is also a *scalar* (hence the dollar)

There is also nothing to stop you using `$arrURLS` (which is a completely separate variable from `@arrURLS`)